# send a member function as an argument to a member of templated class

Tags: c++, function, pointers, templates, lambda

I have a template basic class: i would like to send a member function as a parameter to another function, how can i do it?

```
template <class T>
class GenericButton
{
public:
    GenericButton(const T& t) :m_t(T) {};
    auto& getT() {
        return m_t;
    }
private:
    T& m_t;
};

class Check
{
private:
    bool m_generic;
    void changeType()
    {
        m_generic = !m_generic;
    };
    GenericButton<decltype(changeType)> m_button = GenericButton<decltype(//changetype());  
// maybe lambda
};

int main(){
    auto check = Check();
    auto function = check.m_button.getT();
    function();
}
```

how can i send a function as a template member please?
please advice,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
using Callback_t = std::function<void()>;
GenericButton<Callback_t> m_button{ [this](){ changeType(); } };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aWPa6xzYG). I took the liberty to change `GenericButton` to hold the callback by value; holding it by reference is asking for trouble.